# Input box getting cut off

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an input form and the right side of my input boxes keep getting cut off.  My code is as follows:

HTML/CSS

```css
.add_idea_box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 1110px;

  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;

  border: solid 1px #6a6a6a;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;

  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.add_idea_box_left {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 130px;
  height: 200px;
}

.add_idea_box_left_top {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 0px;
}

.add_idea_box_left_bottom {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.add_idea_box_left_bottom_row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 27px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 85%;
  color: #363636;
}

.red_circle {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background-color: #ff5f57;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.yellow_circle {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background-color: #ffbd2e;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.green_circle {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background-color: #29cb41;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.add_idea_box_right {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 25px;
  border-left: solid 1px #bab6b6;
}

.add_idea_box_right_top {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
}

.add_idea_box_right_bottom {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px;

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #fa8e00 0%,
    #ab0000);
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left top, left bottom,
    from(#fa8e00),
    to(#ab0000));

  border: 1px solid #7d0000;

  -moz-box-shadow:
    0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
    inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow:
    0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
    inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  box-shadow:
    0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
    inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  text-shadow:
    0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.4),
    0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bab6b6;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #bab6b6;
  background: #efeeee;
}

textarea  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bab6b6;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #bab6b6;
  background: #efeeee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xml; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>GroupTrades</title>
<!-- CSS -->
<link type="text/css" href="css/ideaboard2.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen">
</head>
<body>

<!-- ADD AN IDEA BOX -->
<div class="add_idea_box">
  <div class="add_idea_box_left">
    <div class="add_idea_box_left_top">
    </div>
    <div class="add_idea_box_left_bottom">
      <div class="add_idea_box_left_bottom_row">
        <div class="green_circle"></div>5 accepted
      </div>
      <div class="add_idea_box_left_bottom_row">
        <div class="yellow_circle"></div>2 pending
      </div>
      <div class="add_idea_box_left_bottom_row">
        <div class="red_circle"></div>3 rejected
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_idea_box_right">
    <form method="post" action="dashboard.php">
      <div class="add_idea_box_right_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="group" value="<?echo $group;?>">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="Title" autofocus>
        <textarea value="idea" id="idea">Idea</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="add_idea_box_right_bottom">
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add Idea">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

</body>
```

A live version is at: http://quickid.net/test2/ideaboard2.html  ... You can see that the right side of the input box and the text box are both getting cut off and their right borders are not showing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing` property to `input` and `text-area` and style accordingly

CSS

```
.add_idea_box_right_top input[type="text"],
.add_idea_box_right_top textarea{
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have set all of these properties on your `input` element:

- width: 100%
- padding: 10px
- border: 2px

So the `input` element takes up 100% of the width and it *also* has 10px padding both left and right on top of that and 2px border on top of that. They all add up so the total width of your element is more than 100% of the width of the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the padding of this class, so try this one.

FROM THIS:

```
 .add_idea_box_right {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 25px;
    border-left: solid 1px #bab6b6;
}
```

TO THIS:

```
.add_idea_box_right {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: left;
 min-height: 200px;
 padding: 20px 25px 0px 25px;
 border-left: solid 1px #bab6b6;
}
```

Let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because 100% width as suggested is interfering with some of the padding, reduce the width to a smaller percentage and center your input field for it to scale better with increasing resolutions.

Edit: If you inspect element on mozilla you can clearly see where the overlap happens with the pick element thing!